# What makes a piece of software an Engine?

Tags: design, terminology

The descriptor 'Engine' gets thrown around a lot: graphics engine, RegEx engine, AI engine, etc. but what actually makes a piece of software an Engine? Design, Input/Output, Purpose, Size?

Comment: The marketing department.

Comment: @Oded: term 'engine' is commonly used by programmers themselves. Try to find alternatives and you'll see why.

Comment: an engine is what makes the wheels I don't want to be reinventing turn

Comment: @Flexo, so - a library?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

An engine would be something that is "under the hood", so to speak. It is not, or at least very rarely is, visible to the end user. A graphics engine, for instance, drives all the rendering calculations but passes those changes on to the actual environment to be modeled. Input: math. Output: pretty colors. An engine might also have very different working variables than a more high level interface. For instance, in the previous example, it is using raw numerical data to manipulate graphics without worrying about whether something is a shadow or a texture, all of that is abstracted into the equations and matrix operations to be performed by that engine. Think of the Engine as the "Kernel" of a given system while the rest would be more like the "Shell".

To use a real world, CS101 analogy, an engine is just like a car engine. It takes two inputs, air and gas. It then passes them into a chamber, whereupon electricity is used to generate the world's smallest use of arc welding. Stuff then explodes. This produces two outputs, exhaust and a pressure wave which drives a piston. The rest is transferred into wheel motion by the various drive shafts and such. So the Engine is the engine and the car itself is the shell. You could use a car engine for a different purpose, say driving a generator for electricity or a mill to grind grain. You could use different inputs if the Engine has the coatings and such to handle things like ethanol or biodiesel.

To sum it up, an Engine is a piece of software that is usually not found in isolation. It acts as motive force for that piece of software but typically interacts very little if at all with the outside world. Several engines may work together to produce complimentary outputs or may be pipelined together as needed. An engine does not do things related to user experience in an aesthetic sense directly but drives those experiences none the less by motivating dataflow and being responsive enough to allow for good application performance.

Comment: So a driver is the tool that controls the engine & crashes the shell?

Comment: i really liked and benifited from your answer but i think the question was more about how to now this piece of code/software should be called a library or API or engine ? if you can add explaination for this as well it will be perfect answer

Comment: Libraries and APIs operate at a different level than an Engine does. Better to keep it focused on the term at hand than diverge into a potentially endless sea of variations and names.

Answer (score 6):

The [definition of engine](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3aengine) is

noun /ˈenjən/ 
engines, plural

1. A machine with moving parts that converts power into motion
2. A thing that is the agent or instrument of a particular process

#1 is the semantic equivelant to `engine` in the software sense that it causes something to happen. 3D Graphics Engine, takes inputs and converts that to motion on the screen. A regex engine takes inputs and converts them to a different output.

#2 is like using the sentence *an engine of change*. This semantic can be applied to software as well.

Software `engines` are more than frameworks and libraries that passively do things. Software engines act on their own based on inputs, they are not passive, and usually have their own `run loop` to do processing on their own volition.

Answer (score 3):

The closest answer so far, in my opinion, was the one that said it's a marketing thing.

Let's try to think where the use of the word in this context came from.

Certainly car or jet engines aren't called that way because they take input and produce some output. If that were it, then not just functions, but many things in life would be engines.

It's not by coincidence, in my opinion, that a cow is most definitely not an engine, not technically speaking, and not in any sane way of speaking.

Engines use various types of energy and turn it into motion (i.e. a specialized type of energy).

Why do we use it in software? I'd say the most realistic guess is because it simply sounds cool. Why do we call some programmers 'Architects'? Same reason, if you ask me.

Another reason could be that programmers generally like to use metaphors to describe parts of their software, so they could be easier to grasp (because naturally the're often not).

My hunch is that it's bad practice to abuse metaphors in such a way that your application domain is full of them. I think it could be useful when talking to clients, or people who don't know or care about programming. Other than that, simple flow charts and diagrams do the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

Engine is anything that **takes some input, process that input, and delivers something as output**. By this definition, a CMS engine is the part which generates the HTTP response on the fly based on the input. A database engine is what takes the query, draws an execution plan, and the executes it, and returns result.

Technically speaking, even a **cow** is a kind of engine. It takes grass, processes it, and delivers milk.

Don't forget that the term engine is more used in Mechanical engineering, and it does exactly the same.

Another aspect of an engine, is being the core of a system. For example, database engine is the core of any RDMS. However, IDEs to connect to that engine, while taking input and returning result, is not considered an engine.

Comment: +1 for the "milk engine", I was eating yoghurt and nearly choked on it when I read that. ;)

Comment: Your definition would make every function an engine.

Comment: Not every function is a function of its inputs.

Comment: I have to agree. Your explanation sounds a bit blurry and arbitrary.

Comment: A programmer is an engine too. It takes coffee on input and produces code on output.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Maybe I should emphasize the **most important part of a system, or subsystem** to my definition.

Comment: This isn't the same meaning of "engine" to which the question refers.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, an engine is just another word for subsystem, module, or library.  I.E. - one or more components cohesively designed for a specific purpose.

Comment: downvoters: please elaborate. That an engine (e.g, the Quake Engine) is a subsystem, a module, or a library is not obviously false.

Comment: While engine is implemented typically as a subsystem, the term is commonly used only for subsystems "under the hood". They are not used as synonyms.

Comment: The premise of this question is that an engine isn't *just* a subsystem, it's a particular type of subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

An engine is basically software that can be extended to create something.

For example, in gaming, you'll hear a lot about 'something' game engine. This means a particular software was modified and extended to create a totally unique game.

Answer (score 0):

At my job the term seems to mean "A single code file in the format `XEngine.cs` with multiple classes inside that code file, all of which contain nothing but static methods".  I throw up a little inside every time I look at it; might as well be a VB6 module.

I personally wouldn't use the term, it's ambiguous and meaningless (unless, I suppose, you're writing software that simulates an automobile or perhaps a racing game) in most cases; it's like the old "Manager" classes of yore - the name tells you nothing other than "This does a lot of stuff" and usually that means it's a gross violation of `SOLID`.